# Add specific product attribute after title on Woocommerce single products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, title, product

In woocommerce, I am trying to include "brand name" product attributes after the product name/title or underneath in single product page as below;

**Super Shark Mop - Tesco Express**

I would like this brand attribute to be automatically added to title once the product is created.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quiet easy using the following code that will remove the product title to replace it with a custom title including the product attribute "brand name" after it:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_template_single_title', 5 );
function custom_template_single_title() {
    global $product;

    $brand_name = $product->get_attribute('brand-name');

    echo '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">';
    the_title();
    if( $brand_name )
        echo ' - ' . $brand_name;
    echo '</h1>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your assistance. It doesn't work for some reason. It duplicates the title but still doesn't add the brand at the end of it. See screenshot here - [link](https://www.bourbonapples.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/screenshot-www.bourbonapples.co_.uk-2018.07.17-11-14-52.png)

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec the script you helped me with isn't working. Any chance of a fix please?

Comment: it still doesn't show the brand name and also it only duplicates the title. Please see link in comment above.

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec it's an attribute not using a plugin for brands.
Basically, I will like to append the brand name to product titles. So on existing product titles, I just need a code to add in order to **show the brand names automatically at the end of the product titles**

e.g 50L Water Filter System - Dyson

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec many thanks for the script above. It works now. The issue was the attribute name. I used **"brand"** rather than **"brand name"** in the product editor.

However, it still doesn't remove the existing title. Only creates a new title with the attribute affixed, below the product price.

Could you assist with this please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see example here - [link](https://www.bourbonapples.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/example.png)

And result here - [link](https://www.bourbonapples.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/result.png)

Comment: answer accepted, just needs some tweaking which I need your help with. The **remove_action** isn't working and the **add_action** adds title to the wrong place, see images in link above.

Comment: Hi, the code doesn't remove the old title.

Comment: @Helen_zs The code is not made to replace the title, but just to add something to it…

Comment: I understand that, but it displays: first the title with the attribute (witch is perfect) and bellow the original title without attribute.(this shouldn't be displayed).

Comment: You are right! The theme had customization on title. You are the best here!! Thanks! *Any chance to make it show on archive pages too?