# Display product attribute below title on single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I'd like to display the custom attribute `book_author` below the product title on single product pages, like so:

**Product title**

**book_author**

**Price**

I've come across [various solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193427/add-specific-product-attribute-after-title-on-woocommerce-single-products/51195721#51195721) for achieving similar changes to `woocommerce_single_product_summary` but none that has successfully displayed a linked custom attribute between the title and price.

I've achieved the desired result on the shop loop using the following, so if there was a way to adapt this code to apply to single product pages also, that would be ideal.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_book_author_attribute', 5 );
function display_book_author_attribute() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_book_author';
        echo '<span class="attribute-book_author">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>';
    }
}
```

Any and all advice would be hugely appreciated here, thanks so much!

Edit: I can use both action hooks together for the same function, however (to my knowledge) this then ties `<span class>` meaning I'm unable to style the attribute differently on shop pages and product pages, ie:

````
```add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_book_author_attribute', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_book_author_attribute', 5 );
function display_book_author_attribute() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_book_author';
        echo '<span class="attribute-book_author">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>';
    }
}`
````

Answer (score 1):

Use `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action hook. also check here [WooCommerce Visual Hook Guide: Single Product Page](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_book_author_attribute', 5 );
function display_book_author_attribute() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_book_author';
        echo '<span class="attribute-book_author">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, please see my edit above for extra detail re the issue I've had using both action hooks for the same function.