# Woocommerce, show selected attribute title after a product title

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I found this code to show attribute after a title: [Add specific product attribute after title on Woocommerce single products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193427/add-specific-product-attribute-after-title-on-woocommerce-single-products)

```
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_template_single_title', 5 );
function custom_template_single_title() {
    global $product;

    $brand_name = $product->get_attribute('brand-name');

    echo '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">';
    the_title();
    if( $brand_name )
        echo ' - ' . $brand_name;
    echo '</h1>';
}
```

is work but, i try to show only one the selected attribute to appear.

**An example attribute from color: white and black**

The code works like

> "Product Title - White, Color"

What i want to show is

if not selected any attribute

> "Product Title"(not to appear anything)

if selected white, show like

> "Product Title - White"

Comment: Works, but not the best implementation, and your question is: you don't want the title and only the attribute?, if that then you can remove the_title(); from the code

Comment: @Uxell Please explain more, or at least provide a screenshot to clarify your question.

Comment: in this code show an example: attribute color has blue white and green show all of them like: "Product Title - blue, white, green", what i want to do is to show only selected attribute, like selected is white "Product Title - white"

Comment: @Ruvee I edited the question to explain clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code in your functions.php . Replace pa_color with your attribute

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_template_single_title', 5 );
function custom_template_single_title() {
   global $product;

   $brand_name = $product->get_attribute('brand-name');
   $brand_output = '';
   if( $brand_name )
       $brand_output = ' - ' . $brand_name;

   echo sprintf('<h1 class="product_title entry-title">%s %s <span></span></h1>',get_the_title(),$brand_output);
}

function change_title_on_color_change() { 
    global $product;
    if($product->get_type() !== 'variable') return;    
?>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        update_product_title();
    });
    $('select#pa_color').change( function(){
        update_product_title();
    });
    function update_product_title() {
        var color_val = $('select#pa_color option').filter(':selected').val();
        var color_text = $('select#pa_color option').filter(':selected').text();
        if(color_val.length > 0) {
            $('.product_title.entry-title span').text(' - ' + color_text);
        } else {
            $('.product_title.entry-title span').empty();
        }
    }
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product','change_title_on_color_change');
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, but not working changed the 3 #pa_color with attribute slug not working
@Martin

Comment: If your attribute group is Color should be pa_color. Not slugs :)

Comment: Thank you sir i leave your clean code is color but still not working

Comment: added space on first 2 line before ,5 and before ,100 like , 5 and , 100 is worked but the title duplicated

Comment: Are you still using your actions ? If you want to use your actions at echo '</h1>'; add the span e.g  echo '<span></span></h1>';. Also check this - https://prnt.sc/1yfd54o

Comment: thanks for the trick via screenshot but as i mention before the title got duplicate the one with Like what i want "Product Title - xCOLORx" but from bottom "Product Title"

Comment: I have updated my answer with your actions.

Comment: I did as your last code is what I want but the only thing the title get duplicated https://prnt.sc/1yfdy7f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238907/discussion-between-uxell-and-martin-mirchev).

Comment: I have updated my answer and iam in chat